# Report Builder date issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameter-passing, reportbuilder

I have a table with columns unit, department, transaction, transaction_date.

I was able to create the report in Report builder with no issues but then I need a parameter input which only inputs the year and month (transaction period). Example Parameter like Start Period: 202207, End Period: 202208. I can't use the data type date/time in report builder because it gives me the calendar selection. I need to input ex.(202208). I tried couple of things but it's either the field will gray out or it will return an error:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 69
> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

```
declare @DateStart varchar(6)
declare @DateEnd varchar(6)

set @DateStart  = '202207'
set @DateEnd ='202208'


select unit, department, trasaction, transaction_date
from transaction_table
WHERE transaction_date BETWEEN @DateStart and @DateEnd
```

Comment: Whats your question? How to convert the value to a date? Or how to make the UI work to accept the input? If UI just use a datepicker and then truncate the day from the parameter.

Comment: Convert your transaction_date to YYYYMM varchar in the WHERE clause

Comment: @DaleK - yes I can't make the UI work to accept the input I need.

Comment: Either use the datepicker and ignore the day, or add a couple of drop down lists for month / year.

Comment: @alexherm thanks! it worked. I added the convert to the transaction date in the query for the report builder I can get the expected value now.